# Can 案が検討されまして also be used to mean "implemented"?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, hiragana, kana

I'm not sure how to make sense of this section of text.
Either it says that buses were considered for use but ultimately left without stranded passengers, OR that sightseeing buses were used and loaded up with stranded passengers who were taken to stay at hotels.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYzvLs9GEMM&t=0m28s

> また、一時はですね、この立ち往生した人たちをバスに乗せてホテルに避難させるという案も検討されまして、そのための観光バスがですね、こちらに10台ほどずらりと待機していたんですけれども、こちらのバスも1時間ほど前に帰って行きました。

My attempts at making sense of this:

> *At one point, using sightseeing buses were considered to evacuate stuck people to hotels, but ultimately were not used, and left.*

Or

> *At one point, sightseeing buses were used/implemented to evacuate stuck people to hotels. (and therefore departed with the stranded people)*

Answer (score 2):

Your first guess is correct, and the sentence means:

> At one point using sightseeing buses to evacuate stranded people to hotels was considered, but ultimately abandoned, and the buses left.

The title of the video says 立往生**解消** and the reporter says おとといから続いていました立ち往生、つい先ほど**１時間ほど前にすべて解消された**ということなんです, so the buses left without stranded passengers an hour before. The 案 of using buses was 一時は検討された, but not implemented after all.